# how to remove certain alphanumeric characters from a specific column

Tags: postgresql

I have a column that displays certain data in the form of Y14H1050101P01T01.

I want to remove the first 4 alphanumeric characters and the last 6 alphanumeric characters so it reads 1050101 instead.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

We can use a regex replacement here:

```sql
SELECT col, REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '^[A-Z0-9]{4}|[A-Z0-9]{6}$', '', 'g') AS col_out
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

If you want the change to stick, then use an update:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET col = REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '^[A-Z0-9]{4}|[A-Z0-9]{6}$', '', 'g')
WHERE col ~* '^[A-Z0-9]{4}.*[A-Z0-9]{6}$';
```

Comment: Yes that works very much appreciated! Is there a way to permanently replace the old column in the table with this new one?

Comment: Yes, use an update.

Comment: Is there a way to narrow down the data even more to only even values?

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do here.  In any case, I have answered the question you asked.